# Adding four arrays in a single array

Tags: android

I have four arrays lists:

```
List<Integer> meat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> veg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> spice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> dairy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

These arrays are getting data from multiple selection spinners which are populated from static arrays.

I want to be able to store these array lists in a single array list, according to their indices which are assigned in the first array. Can anybody help me or give me a good solution for doing this?

Comment: So, do you want an ArrayList that conatins them all?

Comment: arrl1.addAll(arrl2); However I am not sure of the index.

Comment: Can u please make your question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> meat=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> veg=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> spice=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> dairy=new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(meat);
list.add(veg);
list.add(spice);
list.add(dairy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList from ArrayLists like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> allInfoInOneArray = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
allInfoInOneArray.add(meat);
allInfoInOneArray.add(veg);
allInfoInOneArray.add(spice);
allInfoInOneArray.add(dairy);
```

Now you can be sure, that at the 0 position in allInfoInOneArray is the meat, at the 1st position is the veg data and so on. Then you can get the data like this : `allInfoInOneArray.get(0).get(0) //get the first element of the meats`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) for Android. You may see [Example of SparseArray](http://android.okhelp.cz/sparsearray-instead-hashmap-android-example/).

May it will be helpful to you.